# How to compute the average of start time in excel

Tags: excel, vba

this is my dataset,

```
6:10:00 AM
5:45:00 AM
8:00:00 AM
6:10:00 AM
6:20:00 AM
6:00:00 AM
```

I am currently doing the following,

1. select range -->format cells --> custom --> h:mm:ss
2. I am using the formula =Average(value(text(range,"h:mm:ss")))

I do get a result. But the problem is when i use the same formula and apply it in a different cell, I get a different result each time. Could you please explain why this is occuring?

Comment: Are your times only times or do they include a date that is formatted out?  If they are just times you can use only `=AVERAGE(Range)` and skip the need to make it text then back to a value, Or you can try `=AVERAGE(MOD(Range,1))`

Comment: Doesn't work. Gives the wrong answer! @scott craner

Comment: Then you have a mixture of text that look like times and real times.  You need to deal with that first.

Comment: For your dataset above, when I copy/paste those 6 times into Excel, the formula `=AVERAGE(A1:A6)` give a result of `6:24:10 AM` - is that correct?

Comment: May be you are not using `$` in your range